# Can't figure out why mock method doesn't work

Tags: scala, mockito

I have a mock method

```
def getBlacklist(newList: List[String]) ={
    when(service.getMyBlacklist).thenReturn(newList)
  }
```

when I call it in test section, the return value is null

```
val res = mocks.getBlacklist(List("abcd"))
```

the main function, can someone help me with that? Thanks.

```
if (!services.getMyBlacklist.contains(s"$accountId:$ruleName")) {
                ***
   } else {
       ***
  }
```

Comment: I am assuming that `services` is an instance of some class? Am I right?

Comment: @ Anand Sai, yes, it contains several methods can be used.

Comment: Do you want to return mock value for `getBlackList` wherever it is called in test?

Comment: yes, I want get the value when I call it

Comment: The return type of getBlacklist is absent. Can you specify that?

Comment: it's OngoingStubbing[List[String]]

Comment: hi Anand, are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is mocking is not done correctly. Essentially, what you do is to mock the behaviour of the class such that whenever a method of that class is called in some other class which you are testing, a mocked value is returned. 
Suppose that `services` is an instance of `Service` class as shown below:

```
class Service() {
  def getBlacklist(): List[String]) = {// Some Original code here}
}
```

Now, for the test, use:

```
val service = mock[Service]
val mockList = List("abc") // change according to your use case 
when(service.getBlacklist).thenReturn(mockList)
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: I don't understand the test part, 1) you had a mockList but where should it be used? Same for "getBlacklist" function
2)  what does login means?

Comment: The return type of `getBlacklist` is missing and code will fail at if condition since `getBlackList` type is unit and you are trying to check something.  Can you specify that?

Comment: the return type is List[String], and I want to check if this list of string contains other list of string.

Comment: I have edited the answer.Please check and let me know!!

Comment: Hi i just edited my code, but the result I got is "org.mockito.internal.stubbing.ConsecutiveStubbing@7730ef88", isn't a list of string

Comment: Hi, I forgot to send the mockList as a response. I have edited the code. Let me know if it works!!

Comment: yeah, I add that myself

Comment: Also can your main code which you are trying to mock?